# Facebook messenger send API

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

When a user types a message into my company's custom chat interface, we’re wanting to send that message to the user in FB messenger.  Looking at the send API, I see that it takes a PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN as well as a paged scoped id.

I’m wondering how we acquire those things…is that from a facebook login or something?  Do we need to create a messenger FB app or page...etc in order to even get a PSID to send to them?  I’m a little confused on what this even looks like.

We would also want to use their webhooks when a message is typed into FB messenger, and replicate that message to our company chat conversation…but that webhook requires a PSID and a PAGE_ID.  It really sounds like we have to create a messenger FB page or something to do what we’re wanting to do?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are talking about the Customer Chat Plugin, yes?
 Why would you want to send a message the user send to your page via the Messenger platform, back to them on the Messenger platform …?

Comment: not sure about the customer chat plugin...I guess that's what I'm trying to figure out.  i.e. what do people use to get things like PSIDs and access tokens in order to send messages to a customer via Messenger.  We are wanting to replicate the entire conversation between that user and another user on messenger.  So if user A or B says something in our page, we want both of those to show up in their messenger thread

Comment: Forget it, Facebook won’t allow that. The Messenger Bot platform is for communication between a user and a page.

Comment: ok, when you say a page, you mean I would need to create like a company FB page?  And then if I did, how would I get that info from them in order to use the send api and send them messages?

Comment: I think you first of all need to figure out whether what you want to do is even an applicable use case for messenger ... right now, it doesn’t sound like it. // In general, you get the page-scoped user id, when the user starts messaging your page-bot - the user has to start the conversation, you can not just send messages to arbitrary users.

Comment: right, that makes sense.  Thanks for the input!